# Print only weekdays and exclude weekends from calendar

Tags: java

I have a calendar where I have managed to print all the days in a month. I want to now get rid of or change my code so that it excludes weekends as it will be for a rota and nobody works weekends. I am unsure how to do this, my thoughts suggest an if loop but have tried and am unsure.

My code at the moment:

```
public static String[] teamJedi = {"Andrew", "Sanjay", "Austen"};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (args.length == 2) {
        int year = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        calendar.set(year, month, 1);
    }

    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);     

    int teamSize = teamJedi.length;
    int counter = 0;

    while (calendar.get(Calendar.MONDAY) == month) {
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
        System.out.println(teamJedi[counter++ % 3]);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY
```

to check if the day is a saturday and same for sundays